# C# Windows Form Project Loading Blank On Other Machines

Tags: c#, .net

I searched around but I could not find anything on this.

I have programmed a c# application in VS 2010, targeted to .NET Framework 4.0.  It has a .DLL and a few config files which I have being copied to the output directory upon compilation.  It works great on my computer, I have .NET 4.0 Extended and .NET 4.0 Client installed. I set the build configuration to "release" on "any CPU".

After it compiles I copy all the files from the release directory to a folder on a shared drive, so that multiple computers on the network can execute it.  When I execute it from the computer that I used to develop it, it runs great.  When others try to execute it starts but just shows a small blank form, and that's it.  I make sure that they have .NET 4.0 installed (Both Extended and Client, though I think the full version is what is really required).

I can't for the life of me figure out why it does this.

All machines are running 32 Bit Windows Vista SP2.

Any thoughts? Much appreciation for any help.

Comment: Have you tried using an installer? i.e. click once or something like that.

Comment: Have you checked that your app is using **only** the files in the release folder? Also, have you checked that it works in your own machine if you copy the release folder to somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a lot of things. First, like one comment, you should do a quick Deployment project and try to install on another computer to see how it work.

If you can't do that, here a couple of things to check:

1. It can be a network permission problem. I've seens an .NET application that could not be executed on the network for x reason but worked on the desktop. To check, make sur your user copy it on their computer before executing.
2. I don't think it's a .NET problem because it wouldn't let you start the application.
3. My guess is that one of your control/library (the one that is not showing) does not have the proper reference when run from another computer. To check, run the application "Dependency Walker" (you can find it on google) and see what DLL are missing from other computers.

That's all I can think for now ! Good luck! You just have to use ellimination method and you will find the problem.

Comment: #3 was it! Yep, for all references I set "copy local" equal to true, copied it to the shared directory and voila.  So now I have to go back and eliminate them one by one until I find the library that needs to be separately copied over upon compilation. Or, a likely easier route, your suggestion.   

I would prefer the deployment or installer as well, but I have to get that approved, and that takes time :)  Thank you!!